# what is the default height of TitleBar and default TextSize in Titlebar in android?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

Does anyone know what is the default size of the `TitleBar` and `TitleBarText` in android?

Comment: I think it can be vary depending upon the device

Comment: use hierarchyviewer and find it by yourself

Answer (score 3):

You can find the default height here

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml

The below is for 4.0.3

```
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">48dip</dimen>
<dimen name="action_bar_title_text_size">18dp</dimen>
```

Check the dimens.xml under respective res/values folder

To the comments from Gopal Rao

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml?av=f

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">?textColorHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?textColorHint</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">?textColorLink</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item> // its is in sp not dp 
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

If you look at the topic best practices.

> Quoting "you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to
>   define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and
>   the system scales the size the same as it does for dp".

Comment: out of curiosity! Android says use `sp` as unit for text sizes but why this fellow using text size in `dp` (18dp)...

Comment: @GopalRao i picked it from the link. you can check the source code from your sdk also. I am not sure why

Comment: @GopalRao if you look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html it says use `sp` . i thinks its for the tile text only the `dp`

Answer (score 0):

It can be vary depending upon the device. 
[here](http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php) is the list of all devices with size